# Is big data a fallacy if most phenomena can be mostly described by few variables?

Tags: bigdata

Is big data a fallacy if most phenomena can be mostly described by few variables?

This has confused me. Surely there are big data sets, but there are also cases when the set of significant or explanatory variables is still very small. I've seen e.g. cancer data sets where the number of meaningful variables reduces to < 5% or less as a results of ML techniques.

One could then ask, why gather that heterogenous data in the first place?

Can stronger assumptions or inferring in the design of experiment stages lessen the amount of analysis required later on?

Is it possible that "big data" is "data with a lot of pointless data"?

Comment: Absolutely, big data is what you do when you have no idea what you are doing. A well-though experimental design beats big data any day of the week.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful that usually "big data" means "many *instances*", not necessarily many *variables* (features).

In many problems, one of the main difficulties is the diversity (variance) of the feature values (e.g. in text or image data). In general, a model can only capture this diversity reliably if it is trained with a sufficiently high number of instances, i.e. a representative sample. This is an essential requirement for statistical learning, otherwise the model is very likely to overfit.

So no, in general big data is not a fallacy: in many domains, ML performs much better with large training data. However, there is a fallacy in assuming that big data is required or is sufficient (or both) for ML models to perform well. There are definitely scenarios in which a small training dataset is representative enough, and also scenarios where a big dataset doesn't save a poorly designed task.

Answer (score 1):

Big data generally means a big number of rows, not a big number of columns.

It is not really a notion, statement or argument, therefore cannot be a false one of those, therefore is not a fallacy. :-)

If the question was more: Is there too much hype around Big Data? then that is more interesting. My answer would be there was, maybe 8 to 10 years ago. But I think it is much more a mature proven technology now. There are many now-practical applications built upon analyzing or training on a huge amount of (often rough, often unlabelled) data.

Answer (score 0):

I will reiterate here what Erwan has said. If still having several columns, an ML model trained on big data just rely upon a few, then it means that other columns give no additional information, i.e., they are highly correlated or group-wise correlated. This has nothing to do with the size of the data instead what is inside the data and this is generally true in strict analytical sense as well where we use the notion of rank deficiency while solving system of linear equations.

So no, big data is not a fallacy, the reason of divided opinions on this topic has to do with the fact that designing valuable ML models is a complex task which requires expertise in several domains such as mathematics, statistics and software engineering. Sadly, anyone able to run a piece of prebuilt ML model (`xgboost` or `Keras`) claims to be a data scientist but the actual contribution they bring to the industry is close to none. Hence the rise of this debate.